# How to get memory/cpu values for instance types programatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I want to find out memory/cpu info from AWS instance type pro-grammatically. Let consider I know my instance type is t2.medium. From this instance type information how can I get memory and cpu. This particular instance type has 4 GB RAM and 2 vCPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [describe-instance-types](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html) function.

By calling this you will be able to get all metadata for each instance type.

An example output is below.

```
{
    "InstanceTypes": [
        {
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "CurrentGeneration": true,
            "FreeTierEligible": true,
            "SupportedUsageClasses": [
                "on-demand",
                "spot"
            ],
            "SupportedRootDeviceTypes": [
                "ebs"
            ],
            "BareMetal": false,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "ProcessorInfo": {
                "SupportedArchitectures": [
                    "i386",
                    "x86_64"
                ],
                "SustainedClockSpeedInGhz": 2.5
            },
            "VCpuInfo": {
                "DefaultVCpus": 1,
                "DefaultCores": 1,
                "DefaultThreadsPerCore": 1,
                "ValidCores": [
                    1
                ],
                "ValidThreadsPerCore": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            "MemoryInfo": {
                "SizeInMiB": 1024
            },
            "InstanceStorageSupported": false,
            "EbsInfo": {
                "EbsOptimizedSupport": "unsupported",
                "EncryptionSupport": "supported"
            },
            "NetworkInfo": {
                "NetworkPerformance": "Low to Moderate",
                "MaximumNetworkInterfaces": 2,
                "Ipv4AddressesPerInterface": 2,
                "Ipv6AddressesPerInterface": 2,
                "Ipv6Supported": true,
                "EnaSupport": "unsupported"
            },
            "PlacementGroupInfo": {
                "SupportedStrategies": [
                    "partition",
                    "spread"
                ]
            },
            "HibernationSupported": false,
            "BurstablePerformanceSupported": true,
            "DedicatedHostsSupported": false,
            "AutoRecoverySupported": true
        }
    ]
}
```

This is also possible in the SDKs:

- [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_types)
- [Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#describeInstanceTypes-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstanceTypesRequest-)
- [JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstanceTypes-property)
- [PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#describeinstancetypes)

Comment: Awesome. That is what I was looking for. I can get a lot more info from this regarding network/cpu/ram etc. I knew about  describe-instances but not  describe-instance-types. Thanks

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)